# Why do we add eventListeners in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can anyone please give me a clear explanation on why we add event listeners in useEffect? It always confuses me. I was reading a blog on how to make a navbar fixed on scroll and I saw that the person added the event listener in the useEffect hook. Link to the blog [Change Navbar Style With The Scroll In A Next.Js Website](https://www.techomoro.com/change-navbar-style-with-the-scroll-in-a-next-js-website/)

```
const [clientWindowHeight, setClientWindowHeight] = useState("");

const handleScroll = () => {
     setClientWindowHeight(window.scrollY);
};

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll); 
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a *"side effect"*. A side effect is something that *affects* your component. If you know about pure functions in JavaScript, think about it in the same way.

For instance, a pure function is something that will always return the same value given the same arguments:

```js
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

An impure function is one that has side-effects; i.e. it can output a different output every time:

```js
function add(a, b) {
  let num = Math.random()
  return a + b + num;
}
```

With React, a side effect is something that can't be done during render time, so something like adding an event listener goes in `useEffect` because it has nothing to do with the components state or received props.

Comment: @bopbopbobp can you please explain this clearly? With React, a side effect is something that can't be done during render time, so something like adding an event listener goes in useEffect because it has nothing to do with the components state or received props. Really confused here. If it has nothing to do with the components state, then why does adding even listeners in the jsx work. Can we add the event listeners directly in the jsx? Other than use Effect?

Comment: @MoroOwusuAfriyie No, it's more that a React component's render function (*keep in mind that the **entire** function body of a React function component **is** the render function*) is to be considered a pure function, i.e. no side-effects. Anything that isn't involved in the function inputs(*props*)/output(*JSX*) would be considered a side-effect. The `useEffect` hook is a way to maintain ***expected*** side-effects in a sane and logical, controlled way.

Comment: @MoroOwusuAfriyie "Can you add event listeners directly to JSX?" Sure, you do each time you add an `onClick` handler to a rendered element for example. But because the component isn't rendering the browser `window` it must use an intentional side-effect (*useEffect*) to add the listener.

Comment: @Drew Reese thank you